# Running Javascript code inside a Python function

Tags: javascript, python, syntax-error

I am trying to run javascript code inside python function in Colab.This is my code(The main block to look up is this `startStreamUpload` function). Btw, I am relly new to Javascript but just at some point forced to make use of it.

```
def sendConnOffer(port):
  '''
  Make POST req from JS to the connected VM (server). Sends the WebRTC stream offer in POST req
  '''
  js = Javascript('''
    // START JS code
    /** 
     * prints the logs to cell output inside notebook
     */
    function printLog (text) {
      document.querySelector("#output-area").appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }

    // peer connection
    let pc = null;
    /**
     * creates a peer connection, opens the device streams then calls negotiate() to connect with server
     * @param serverUrl: url of other peer. Server in this case
     */
   // HERE // async function startStreamUpload(serverUrl) {
      const connectionConfig = { sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan' };
      pc = new RTCPeerConnection(connectionConfig);
      
      const streamConfig = {
        audio: false,
        video: { width: 640, height: 480 }
      };
      let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConfig); // access the webcam stream
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        pc.addTrack(track, stream); // tracks can be video/audio. Video in our case
      });

      // negotiate the deal with server
      await negotiate(serverUrl);
    }

   .......
   .......
   .......
  
  """)
  
  
  display(js) # make the provided HTML, part of the cell
  # the server running in Colab VM
  serverUrl = f"https://localhost:{port}/"
  print("ServerURL: ", serverUrl)
  # call the startStreamUpload() JavaScript function
  jsFuncToCall = eval_js('startStreamUpload({})'.format(serverUrl))
  print("jsFuncToCall: ", jsFuncToCall)
  return 


sendConnOffer(1234)
```

This is the full error message:

```
     89   print("ServerURL: ", serverUrl)
     90   # call the startStreamUpload() JavaScript function
---> 91   jsFuncToCall = eval_js('startStreamUpload({})'.format(serverUrl))
     92   print("jsFuncToCall: ", jsFuncToCall)
     93   return

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py in eval_js(script, ignore_result, timeout_sec)
     38   if ignore_result:
     39     return
---> 40   return _message.read_reply_from_input(request_id, timeout_sec)
     41 
     42 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 

MessageError: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: What have you done to try and determine what the error is referring to?

Comment: Can you show the full error. Does it give a line?

Comment: You're starting the JS with triple-singlequote, but ending it with triple-doublequote.

Comment: @Barmar fixed it. But still no result.

Comment: `// HERE //` is commenting out the  beginning of the `startStreamUpload` function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the around the argument to `startStreamUpload`, since it's a string.

```
jsFuncToCall = eval_js('startStreamUpload("{}")'.format(serverUrl))
```

Comment: Thank but now in the same line another error occured:  `Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: The errors are happening in the JavaScript code. Python will report all those errors as happening on the `eval_js()` line.